# Why I am able to access mongodb without running local mongo server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am beginning with server side programming by following a online course. As per my understanding, we use `mongoose.connect(url)` to connect to `mongodb` where url can be `localhost url` on which mongodb server is running.

But recently I forgot to run the local mongodb server using [mongod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongod). When I ran my node app with following code, it worked just fine :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp');

const {Todo} = require('./../server/models/todos');
const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');


Todo.remove({}).then((result)=>{
  console.log(result);
});
```

It worked fine with no error even though mongodb server was not running. When I checked the local database using `Robo-3T tool`, the `documents` were removed. I have verified this again.

I am unable to understand why my node app was able to connect to `mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp` even though mongodb server was not running on `localhost:27017.` Also, why Robo-3T tool was able to connect to this `localhost: 27017` if server was not running.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think the mongod server __wasn't__ running? It appears that it was.

Comment: I never ran mongod --dbpath command and had no instance of terminal running it. Please tell if i am missing anything. Is it possible that it was running in background ? How can i check this ? Thanks

Comment: Yep, perfectly possible.

Comment: "how can I check this" - `ps aux | grep mongod`, for example

Comment: Thanks. The process for mongodb is running there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mongodb` server was already running. Looks like the server does not shuts down on closing the terminal. It still runs in background. We have to close it using `Ctrl+C`.

More info: [mongodb doesn't stop when I close terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/782639/brew-mongodb-doesnt-stop-when-i-close-terminal)

Thanks @Sergio Tulentsev.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple, the process is running in the background. If you search for 'services' - (in windows), scroll down to check for MongoDb, you will see that the process is running (Started). If set to Automatic, it starts up even after every restart.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason is MongoDB server runs as a service in the **background**. Even if you restart your computer, it may be running.

I recognized at my win 10, MongoDB server is automatically started. So, you don't need to run mongod on your local.

At win 10 you can check it by:

1. type services in the search box;
2. open Services window;
3. Find MongoDB Server in the list;
4. Check Startup Type.

Probably your startup type is Automatic, you can change MongoDB Server startup type here.

Comment: I was able to stop it from running using your method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when you don't stop the server explicitly and close your terminal.The server is running in background.You can see that in your task manager as well. Press Ctrl+C to quit and it will stop your server.